# IBM ICP Auth-pdp does not respond

Tags: kubernetes, mariadb, ibm-cloud-private

At task: Waiting for auth-pdp to start auth-pdp pod could not reach mariadb-0. Has anyone faced this issue before?

```sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:09 --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to mariadb port 3306: Operation timed out
```

I have checked mariadb container if it is running, then realized it has no ip address.

```sh
kubectl -n kube-system get pods -o wide
...
mariadb-0                                             1/1       Running             0          7m        <none>       34.65.234.2
...
```

Then I tried port-forward mariadb I could reach from local terminal

```sh
kubectl -n kube-system port-forward mariadb-0 8080:3306 &
[1] 9483
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 3306
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 3306
^C
curl localhost:3306
5.5.5-10.2.17-MariaDB-1:10.2.17+maria~bionic~rHO8ewF5���vtf~is&`4#M=mysql_native_password!��#08S01 Got packets out of order
```

I exed auth-pdp pod try curl another services

```sh
bash-4.4# env | grep -i mongo
MONGODB_SERVICE_PORT=27017
MONGODB_PORT_27017_TCP=tcp://10.0.0.181:27017
MONGODB_PORT_27017_TCP_PROTO=tcp
MONGODB_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR=10.0.0.181
MONGODB_SERVICE_HOST=10.0.0.181
MONGODB_PORT_27017_TCP_PORT=27017
MONGODB_PORT=tcp://10.0.0.181:27017
bash-4.4# curl 10.0.0.181:27017
It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.
```

I reviewed the interfaces of mariadb pod and found the following:

```sh
calie6c068a340a: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 451  bytes 27552 (27.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 348  bytes 27089 (27.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

caliee45ca146c2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 191  bytes 14176 (14.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 87  bytes 9236 (9.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

calif6e93cd4328: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7302  bytes 1203027 (1.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7645  bytes 4818796 (4.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:1ff:feee:54b4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:01:ee:54:b4  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5  bytes 446 (446.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1460
        inet 10.240.0.11  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 10.240.0.11
        inet6 fe80::4001:aff:fef0:b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 42:01:0a:f0:00:0b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 753548  bytes 3753160696 (3.7 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 697800  bytes 219630854 (219.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 214601  bytes 54627282 (54.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 214601  bytes 54627282 (54.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The ens4 NIC has the same IP address as the Node where the pod is running. It does not got a unique address. Then the following resolves:

```sh
k exec -it auth-idp-bkqwf -c init-mariadb bash
bash-4.4# curl 10.240.0.11:3306 --output dummy.txt
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   148    0   148    0     0   144k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  144k
```

Comment: Mariadb has endpoint:
```bash
kubectl -n kube-system get svc
mariadb                        ClusterIP   10.0.0.162   <none>        3306/TCP            2h
```

Comment: Anything interesting in auth-pdp pod logs? `kubectl logs auth-pdp_pod_name`

Comment: Full of with:
```bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:09 --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to mariadb port 3306: Operation timed out
```

Comment: apparently there's an issue with network plugin of the mariadb-0 pod. Can you check it's logs as well?

Comment: I have fix some of the issues:
When I change mariadb to the node Ip address, then the curl command succed.

Comment: I also recognized my node does not have IP address:
```bash
NAME          STATUS    ROLES                                 AGE       VERSION       INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION    CONTAINER-RUNTIME
34.65.234.2   Ready     etcd,management,master,proxy,worker   15m       v1.11.1+icp   <none>        <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS   4.15.0-1032-gcp   docker://18.3.0
```

Comment: CNI plugin issue, should be explained in kubelet logs `/var/log/kubelet.log`

Comment: There is no evidence for CNI issue in kubelet logs.

Comment: Does your cluster meet the minimum hardware requirements? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_3.2.0/supported_system_config/hardware_reqs.html

Comment: Yes, it does. It has 16vCPU, 30 G Mem and 260gb storage

Comment: Is this a single node cluster? 32 GB or more Mem is needed. Also "If multiple cluster roles are installed on one node, the disk requirement is the sum of the disk requirement for each role."
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_3.2.0/supported_system_config/hardware_reqs.html#runtime-space